# Responsive nav with jquery, dropdowns only open when hovered over, the dropdown arrow won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website for a project and i'm not allowed to use frameworks (so no bootstrap but jquery is allowed.), earlier i had a problem where the navigation bar when collapsed (screen width under 800px) has all the individual links expanded, rather than being in individual categories. 
I've now fixed that but i've now got this problem where the menu's wont stay open / the arrows when clicked just take you to the subcategories heading. This makes the site unusable for mobiles essentially as no one will think to long click a tab to open each one.

I've uploaded this website to 
[here](http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/webdev/index.html)

The Html nav bar

```
<nav role="navigation" id="cssmenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="courses.html">Courses</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="courses/media.html">Digital Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="courses/webdev.html">Web Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="courses/journalism.html">Journalism</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="courses/infocomms.html">Information & Communications</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="facilities/society.html">Societies</a></li>
            <li><a href="facilities/jobs.html">Jobs and Placements</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="facilities/library.html">Library</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub active"><a href="manchester.html">Manchester & Student Life</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="manchester/travel.html">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="manchester/attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="manchester/night.html">Nightlife</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="help.html">Student Help</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="help/finance.html">Finance</a></li>
            <li><a href="help/union.html">Student Union</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="help/assist.html">Assistance</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

The Jquery script

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Cache the elements we'll need
var menu = $('#cssmenu');
var menuList = menu.find('ul:first');
var listItems = menu.find('li').not('#responsive-tab');

// Create responsive trigger
menuList.prepend('<li id="responsive-tab"><a href="#">Digi-Co</a></li>');

// Toggle menu visibility
menu.on('click', '#responsive-tab', function(){
    listItems.slideToggle('fast');
    listItems.addClass('collapsed');
});
});
} )( jQuery );
```

The css can also be found 
[here](http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/webdev/cssmenu/styles.css)

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you.